Issues with Wayland and X11 in Nvidia Gpu
I have a PC with a Nvidia Gpu RTX 3080 and I'm having issues with Wayland and X11.
When I switch to X11 my Gpu is detected, but my terminal gets buggy (I saw the solution here where one lad swapped to Wayland and the bug was fixed). Even IntelliJ Idea sometimes flickers. Currently it's ok, the only problem that annoys me most is the unresponsive terminal (delays when I type, duplicated chars)
I swapped to Wayland and the terminal problems went away except after I put my PC to rest, it does not render the UI properly and I have to reboot, after which my GPU is not detected. This problem started one month ago. I think this might be connected with the fact that I'm on a desktop and my processor doesn't have integrated graphics, since it's a Ryzen 5700X.

What Ubuntu release are you running, which kernel, and which Nvidia driver?  Ubuntu 24.04 is only offering up to Nvidia driver 535 until more testing is done on the 545 and 550 (so I hear).

I'm running Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS, kernel: 6.5.0-28-generic and my Nvidia driver is: 535.171.04, CUDA Version: 12.2.
